# how to caculate the avg of column from a csv which does not have headers with powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

The data array inside the csv which does not have headers(shoudl be: pkg, pp0, pp1, dram, time):

```
37.0036,27.553,0,0,0.100111
35.622,26.1947,0,0,0.200702
34.931,25.5656,0,0,0.300765
34.814,25.4795,0,0,0.400826
34.924,25.5676,0,0,0.500888
34.8971,25.5443,0,0,0.600903
```

if I want to get the avg value of the columns and make the output like:

```
The avg of Pkg: xxx
The avg of pp0: xxx
The avg of pp1: xxx
The avg of time: xxx
```

how can I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your coding attempts at this?

Comment: When using `Import-CSV` also use the `-Header` parameter to specify names for the columns, then you can use the names as normal.

For calculating the average, look into the [Measure-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.2) command

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am a rookie here. 
I have try $powerlog=import-csv .\a.csv, but powershell report error:
import-csv : The member "0" is already present.
At line:1 char:11
+ $powerlog=import-csv .\a.csv
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvC
   ommand

my reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com, "readin-csv-and-calculate-average-value? " that question have headers in the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `Import-CSV`, PowerShell references the first row as the header row. The error you're getting,

> import-csv : The member "0" is already present.

Is because there is already a header name of 0 in the header row. To give new names to the headers, use the `Import-CSV -Header` command to give manual names in the csv file.

From here, you can use the `Measure-Object` command to determine the averages

```
$myData = Import-Csv .\a.csv -Header pkg,pp0,pp1,dram,time
Write-Host "The avg of Pkg: $(($myData | Measure-Object -Property pkg -Average).Average)"
Write-Host "The avg of pp0: $(($myData | Measure-Object -Property pp0 -Average).Average)"
Write-Host "The avg of pp1: $(($myData | Measure-Object -Property pp1 -Average).Average)"
Write-Host "The avg of time: $(($myData | Measure-Object -Property time -Average).Average)"
```